# syntax error while using "with rollup" in store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm first time trying to write a stored procedure in sql server and the codes as below. Here when I add "with rollup" at the end of the query, it shows error "Incorrect syntax **near the keyword with"**

```
DROP PROCEDURE FIRSTPROCEDURE
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE FIRSTPROCEDURE
@startdate nchar(8), @enddate nchar(8)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select Date, SUM(QT1), SUM(QTY2), SUM(qTY3) FROM dbo.TABLE1
where date between @startdate and @enddate 
group by Date
order by Date
WITH ROLLUP
END
GO
```

And tried to execute the procedure as below :

```
exec firstprocedure '20120501', '20120525'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`With rollup` needs to come before the `order by`. It's related to the `group by`

```
select Date, SUM(QT1), SUM(QTY2), SUM(qTY3) FROM dbo.TABLE1 
where date between @startdate and @enddate  
group by Date WITH ROLLUP 
order by Date
```

Also, you'll avoid a whole bunch of issues if you store and query your dates using the date datatype